# How a server differs between two requests?

Tags: web, networking, server, request, computer-science

Can someone please explain how the server differs between the two requests [www.google.com/maps](http://www.google.com/maps) and [www.google.com/inbox](http://www.google.com/inbox)?

Comment: The server knows what URL you typed.  When the server gets the request, it sees `/maps` or `/inbox` in the request and can respond accordingly

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about how web requests work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best for you to see for yourself.  If you're on Linux/MacOs, go to a shell and type `nc -l 8080`.  Then open a web browser and look at, say, `http://localhost:8080/a/b/c/d`.

The `nc` command listens on port 8080 and just prints out whatever it receives.  Here it's serving as a bad web browser that listens for requests but has no idea how to respond.

You'll see that the first two lines of what it receives are:

```
GET /a/b/c/d HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
```

followed by other information the browser things the server might need.